# Distorted sound on Fedora 36

Tags: audio, fedora, thinkpad, sound-card, distortion

I am using Fedora 36 on my ThinkPad x250.
The output of the speakers is quite low therefore I tried tweaking it using Alsamixer.

However, the results were not satisfying hence, I used other solutions on the web and I guess that I installed PulseAudio. After that the sound is quite distorted and low. Can someone help me?

I used the `inxi -Ax` to find the running drivers and I got this:

```
shahzeb@fedora ~]$ inxi -Ax
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.18.6-200.fc36.x86_64 running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.52 running: yes
```

Comment: Did you have any luck answering this? I have nearly the same output you do and same symptoms.